Is there any approach to notify windows that the registry item Scancode Map is changed?
By editing "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map", I can remap the scancode passed to the applications.
But each time the modification is applied, I must reboot my pc to make the change effecitive.
So is there any method such as a winapi call or restarting the relative process to notify the system that the scancode map is changed and adopt the new remappings?
I have tried restarting the explorer.exe, but it seems doesn't matter.
The following code block also makes no effect.
SendNotifyMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0 );

Maybe the scancode map was loaded into the kernel when the system started?

Are you asking 1) how to monitor a registry key for changes or 2) how to alert a user of the need to reboot (or maybe how to avoid the need to reboot)?

Not that case. Make the modification of scancode map into effect seems to require the reboot action. But it was very desctructive to my daily work.
The context is that my external keyboard was broken for some reasons and I must edit the registry to make it work properly.
While it would also affect my built-in kb, and when I switch my keyboards, I have to modify the registry and reboot again.
That was too unacceptable.

Words in the braces of (2) is exactly what I want.
